# Is there an HKEY_Current_User equivalent of HKey_Classes_Root\Record?

Tags: registry

For `HKey_Class_Root\CLSID` I found the equivalent to be `HKey_Current_User\Software\Classes\CLSID` but looking in the registry I didn't see "Record" in the same location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

how about

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes?

and

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes

What you see in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT actually is a merge of these two keys (and it depends on your permissions in which of these two branch new entries made under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT will be created).

Comment: Does that mean I can write to one or the other? Or do I need to write to both?  I'm trying to set up a per-user install that doesn't require admin priviledges

Comment: What tool do you use to build your installer? If a standard user will install your product, the entry will go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes. Typically your installer will take care of this.

Comment: I'm writing the installer in WiX, but I think that should work.  I just didn't see a pre-existing folder for "Record" under HKCU, whereas I did for CLSID so that's why I was wondering.  Most of they registry stuff was decompiled from the one created by Visual Studio

Comment: Yes, that should work. WiX/MSI will create the key in the correct branch, depending on the value of the ALLUSERS property afaik.